# what is the difference in the codes with ramda.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am trying to learning fp recently and try to use ramda.js into my project but I met some problems.

The goal of my code is I want to add `result` prop with some initial values into each element of the `list` array, but it didn't work as expected.

Here is my code:

```js
var list = [{name: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'}, {name: 'baz'}]
var list1 = R.clone(list)

var getResultList = R.times(R.identity)

// what's the difference between them ??
// it worked as expected if I wrap assoc fn into arrow function and transfer it to fn
var mapAssocResult= R.map(e=> R.assoc('result', getResultList(2), e))
// it didn't work as expected if I just transfer it as param of map fn
var mapAssocResult1= R.map(R.assoc('result', getResultList(2)))

list = mapAssocResult(list)
list1 = mapAssocResult1(list1)

list[0].result === list[1].result //false
list1[0].result === list1[1].result // true
// it seems that all result props point to the same array reference, but why?
```

is there something I need to notice using Ramda.js ?

Maybe my thinking in using Ramda.js is totally wrong, so is there more reasonable way to achieve my goal in Ramda.js ?

thanks a lot.

Comment: I have no real suggestion beyond the one from Scott Christopher below, but I would note that `R.range(0)` is probably more descriptive, and certainly more concise than `R.times(R.identity)`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you are seeing is due to `getResultList(2)` being evaluated too early in `R.map(R.assoc('result', getResultList(2)))`. This ends up being equivalent to `R.map(R.assoc('result', [0, 1]))`, which will assign the same `[0, 1]` instance to each element's `result` property.

The extra arrow function prevents `getResultList(2)` from being evaluated until the mapping function is applied to each element of the array, resulting in a new and unique instance of `[0, 1]` for each `result` property.

Comment: thanks a lot, by the way, so is there more reasonable way to achieve my goal in Ramda.js ? because I notice the examples of the articles about ramda.js always use point-free style to achieve something.

Comment: Points-free is a good tool that can help make certain code more readable.  But don't make a fetish of it.  If we came up with a points-free version of this, it would probably become a lot *less* readable.  So here it's not worth it.